# Failed to create component for 'dialog' reason: java.awt.HeadlessException

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After updating gradle to version 3.0.0-beta3 I have this error when I try to display a dialog box to ask for the password of the key.

I tried to add `System.setProperty('java.awt.headless', 'false')` but it did not work and I found nothing very new on google ....

> Error:(20, 1) Failed to create component for 'dialog' reason:
>   java.awt.HeadlessException
>
> > java.awt.HeadlessException (no error message)

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
        def storePassword = ''
        def keyPassword = ''
        if (System.console() == null) {
            new SwingBuilder().edt {
                dialog(modal: true, title: 'Enter password', alwaysOnTop: true, resizable: false, locationRelativeTo: null, pack: true, show: true) {
                    vbox {
                        label(text: "Please enter store passphrase:")
                        def input1 = passwordField()
                        label(text: "Please enter key passphrase:")
                        def input2 = passwordField()
                        button(defaultButton: true, text: 'OK', actionPerformed: {
                            storePassword = input1.password;
                            keyPassword = input2.password;
                            dispose();
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            storePassword = System.console().readPassword("\nPlease enter store passphrase: ")
            keyPassword = System.console().readPassword("\nPlease enter key passphrase: ")
        }

        if (storePassword.size() <= 0 || keyPassword.size() <= 0) {
            throw new InvalidUserDataException("You must enter the passwords to proceed.")
        }

        storePassword = new String(storePassword)
        keyPassword = new String(keyPassword)

        android.signingConfigs.Keys.storePassword = storePassword
        android.signingConfigs.Keys.keyPassword = keyPassword
}
```

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2826, was closed because the reporter could no longer reproduce on Gradle 3.3, but it will likely come back with 4.0.

Comment: Just stopping the Gradle daemon helped me,  "./gradlew --stop".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add `System.setProperty('java.awt.headless', 'false')` before  `import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder` and kill gradle deamon with `./gradlew --stop`

it give you something liket that :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

System.setProperty('java.awt.headless', 'false')

import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
```

Comment: add before - where?

Comment: @StAlex before "import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder"

Comment: Does this solution still work for you?  I can't get it to work with `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'` exactly as you have written when using `gradlew assembleObaGoogleRelease` on https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/onebusaway-android/tree/release-builds-broken

Comment: add this System.setProperty('java.awt.headless', 'false') to before you create the SwingBuilder object( after if (System.console() == null) ). it worked for me

Comment: Thanks Qing, only that worked for me, declaring it on the top of the build file wasn't.

Comment: Excellent. This fixed the final string of problems encountered when moving from Cordova/Android 5 to 7. I added to build-extras.gradle, works great.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem you have to add these 3 line exactly in this order (other orders don't work)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder

System.setProperty('java.awt.headless', 'false')
```

Comment: Working example is here: https://github.com/filol/MyApplication/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Comment: My solution is actually working. I use it every days !

Comment: No, it wasn't until you edited your answer exactly as mine. Unfortunatly for you stackoverflow allows us to see your previous answer.

Comment: It's exactly the same as what I wrote. I just wrote it in the same way as you do. You can look at the code matches what I wrote before and it's not the same order of line.

Answer (score 3):

```
def doPromptForPassword(msg) {
if (System.console() == null) {
    System.setProperty('java.awt.headless', 'false') // worked for me
    def ret = null
    new SwingBuilder().edt {
        dialog(modal: true, title: 'Enter password', alwaysOnTop: t
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it finally worked when I added `System.setProperty('java.awt.headless', 'false')` twice:

- immediately after import
- after `System.console() == null` check

But then it happens be ok with only after `System.console() == null` check.

Don't forget to `./gradlew --stop` as mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error while building a release version of my Ionic-**Cordova** app.
All I did was assigning **"storePassword"** in my **build.json** File in my project root directory

**build.json**

```
{
    "android": {
        "debug": {
            "keystore": "./my-release-key.keystore",
            "storePassword": "password",
            "alias": "name",
            "password" : "password",
            "keystoreType": "",
            "packageType": "apk"
        },
        "release": {
            "keystore": "./my-release-key.keystore",
            "storePassword": "password",
            "alias": "name",
            "password" : "password",
            "keystoreType": "",
            "packageType": "apk"
        }
    }
}
```