# Gradle build fail with ....Failed to create component for 'dialog' reason: java.awt.HeadlessException

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, ionic3

I am getting the following error each time I try to sign my apk file while using Android Studio or the CLI:

```
BUILD FAILED in 4s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\coderepo\puppydogmobile\puppydogmobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 148

* What went wrong:
Failed to create component for 'dialog' reason: java.awt.HeadlessException
> java.awt.HeadlessException (no error message)
```

I have seen a lot of comments on this error but no fixes only workarounds which don't work in many cases. Can anyone tell me if there as been an update to this problem. 
I tried this solution: setting

```
System.setProperty('java.awt.headless', 'false') from 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45909265/failed-to-create-component-for-dialog-reason-java-awt-headlessexception
```

it didn't work'

The last advice I got was to hardcode my keystore pswd in the platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle file like this:

```
def doPromptForPassword(msg) {
    if (System.console() == null) {
        def ret = 'password'   
        new SwingBuilder().edt {
            dialog(modal: true, title: 'Enter password', alwaysOnTop: true, resizable: false, locationRelativeTo: null, pack: true, show: true) {
                vbox {
                    label(text: msg)
                    def input = passwordField()
                    button(defaultButton: true, text: 'OK', actionPerformed: {
                        ret = input.password;
                        dispose();
                    })
                }
            }
        }
```

which by any stretch is a poor hack and security risk and it didn't work. I really need to know what is the latest solution to this problem!

THIS IS MY ENVIRONMENT
Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (C:\Users\maenn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.4.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 17 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\maenn\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v8.11.4 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 5.6.0
   OS                : Windows 10

Also my target is set like this:

```
 defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
      minSdkVersion 16
      targetSdkVersion 26
    }
```

I also use Android Studio 3.3.2 to build apks and bundles.